# Call an action upon submitting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

On my Rails app, I use `simple_form`. I want to call an action from UsersController when I submit a form in the `edit` view.

Code:

*edit.html.erb*

```
<div>
  <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :profile_image %>
    <%= f.submit %> // I want to call "confirm" action from UsersController here
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I thought replacing the submit line with `<%= f.submit 'submit', :input_html => { :action => "confirm" } %>` would work, but it didn't; the attribute was updated without the action "cofirm" being called.

I think my problem is I'm attempting to call two actions, `update` and `confirm` in UsersController at the same time. However, I am not sure how to do a workaround to solve the problem.

What I want to achieve is if user changes his email, I want to send a confirmation email to verify it. So when the user updates his email attribute by sending the form, I call the `confirm` action to send an email with a link that holds a parameter. When the user clicks the link, he's directed to the application with the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its bad idea to do business logic inside controller. Let controller handle only render and redirects. You can do this with the help of callbacks or ActiveRecord::Observer. Here's callback example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :check_for_email_edits


  def check_for_email_edits
    if email_changed?
      MyMailer.send_confirmation_instructions(self)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: This was a perfect workaround. How could I not think of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you, but know is this a best idea or not?

```
 <%=  simple_form_for( @user, :url => { :action => "confirm" }) do |f| %>
```

But this code only call the `confirm` action of user controller when submit the form. If you want to check certain condition before submit the form then you can use `jquery` as client side validation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your method calls `confirm` action instead of `update` action. I concluded it's not possible to call two action from  the submitting button.